# How to convert RxJava 1 Subject to RxJava 2 Subject using RxJavaInterop?

Tags: rx-java2

I'm trying to convert a PublishSubject:

```
rx.subjects.PublishSubject<String> sj = rx.subjects.PublishSubject.create();
PublishSubject<String> sj2 = RxJavaInterop.toV2Subject(sj);
```

But the IDE said that can not apply rx.subjects.Subject< T, T> to rx.subjects.PublishSubject< java.lang.String>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't convert it to a v2 `PublishSubject` because subject implementations are final and can't wrap other subjects, thus, as the method's return type indicates, you have to use a `io.reactivex.subjects.Subject<String>` as a type:

```
rx.subjects.PublishSubject<String> sj = rx.subjects.PublishSubject.create();
io.reactivex.subjects.Subject<String> sj2 = RxJavaInterop.toV2Subject(sj);
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the answer!